# Ansible molecule test framework fails to gather facts from docker image of centos7

Tags: python, bash, docker, ansible, centos

I am trying to test a simple ansible script I have made using molecule. I am currently setting up molecule and have been following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93urFkaJQ44

When I run `molecule test` I get this error (this is verbose, -vvv output):

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [instance]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to create temporary directory.In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\", for more error information use -vvv. Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp `\"&& mkdir \"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1631621484.12-47224-231505895998260 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1631621484.12-47224-231505895998260=\"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1631621484.12-47224-231505895998260 `\" ), exited with result 1", "unreachable": true}
```

It says that this error is caused by the converge script, as it errors in the `PLAY Converge` section.

Converge.yml

```
---
- name: Converge
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
- import_playbook: ../../setUpVm.yml
```

/.ansible exists as it returns:

```
collections  cp  galaxy_token  tmp
```

Any help appreciated.

**Update** Setting gather_facts: no makes the test run to completion. This "fix" however is not idea.

Comment: `Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\"` <= what have you done about that? See `config_options:` in [ansible provisioner documentation](https://molecule.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#id7). Else you should check which user you connect as and what are its permissions. I've never had that problem running molecule against any flavor of docker image before. Meanwhile most of my my tests run with `become:true`

Answer (score 1):

Your docker engine has restarted. Do a simple

```
molecule destroy && molecule create
```

will permit you to successfully run your tests.

Another clue may be a filesystem problem. It often occurs within multiple operation systems, like running a docker inside a WSL2 virtualized kernel on Windows. Try to change your molecule against checked source tree to a native linux path.

Comment: This was the cause of the "Failed to create temporary directory" error in my case. Thanks.